# React cannot map through prop array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I fetch an api on `componentDIdMount()` then store the json to a state then I pass that state as a prop, I have no problem showing the data except on arrays.

```
<Component details={this.state.details} />
```

json:

```
    {
    "adult": false,
    "backdrop_path": "/qonBhlm0UjuKX2sH7e73pnG0454.jpg",
    "belongs_to_collection": null,
    "budget": 90000000,
    "genres": [
    {
    "id": 28,
    "name": "Action"
    },
    {
    "id": 878,
    "name": "Science Fiction"
    },
    {
    "id": 35,
    "name": "Comedy"
    },
    {
    "id": 10751,
    "name": "Family"
    }
    ]
    }
```

then I try to map the genres:

```
<div className={style.genre}>
   {details.genres.map(g => (
      <span key={g.id}>{g.name}</span>
   ))}
</div>
```

But then I get `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, I don't know why this is happening because I'm able to do `details.budget`

Comment: Can you share more info, like where are you calling your API, how are you storing `details`? As the code you have shared is working okay on console so there might be problem perhaps with the way of implementation like using `details` way before it has been assigned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to read data before you get the result from api. 
so write the map function as

```
    {details&&details.genres&&details.genres.map(g => (
      <span key={g.id}>{g.name}</span>
   ))}
```

In react Initially when component is mounted, `render()` function is called and then `componenentDidMount()` is called in which you fetch data. So Initially `details` is empty. So you need to write the condition.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I did something similar before which is /*details.genres !== null &&*/ but I still go the same error so what does the condition /*details &&*/ mean?

Comment: That might be because details.genres is undefined. And undefined!==null returns true.